# How to access line items metadata in Stripe checkout session using PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments, metadata

How do you access the line items **metadata** for each product when using **php** and **alllineitems**?

`$checkout_lineitems = $stripe->checkout->sessions->allLineItems( $_GET['session_id'], [] );`

There seems to be no clear documentation for this.

Also if I set the name and description for a product as follows:

`'product_data' => ['name' => 'Item 1','description' => 'My item']`

How do I retrieve the description? If I use the following line, it returns the name!

`$checkout_lineitems->data[0]->description`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By default, retrieving a Checkout Session's line items will give you back the full Price object, but just the Product ID (see [api ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-line_items-data-price-product)). If you want to get back the full product object you need to [expand](https://stripe.com/docs/expand#lists) `data.price.product` like this:

```
$checkout_lineitems = $stripe->checkout->sessions->allLineItems(
$_GET['session_id'], ['expand' => ['data.price.product']] );
```

After making that change, you should be able to access the product description.

```
$checkout_lineitems->data[0]->price->product->description;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the expand function (as suggested by karbi), I can now get the metadata that I added as follows:

```
$checkout_lineitems->data[0]->price->product->metadata->mycustomfield
```

The following links explain expanding objects in more detail with Stripe:

- https://stripe.com/docs/expand
- https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects